# Wi-Fi taking up lot of memory

Tags: wifi, memory, mojave, activity-monitor

Since the last major upgrade to macOS Mojave, I have the **Wi-Fi** process taking up a lot of memory and in an exponentially way. Time to time I need to force quit it in Activity Monitor because it takes too much memory (around 5 GB). Did anyone else faced the same issue and was able to resolve?

I am using a MacBook Pro 15-inch 2017 with macOS Mojave 10.14.

[image]

Edit: I've recently noticed that the Wi-Fi process uses a lot of memory when connecting to the internet through personal hotspot on iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last macOS Mojave release (10.14.4), this problem has disappeared. Therefore, it seems that they tackled it; at least it's been a while since I've had this problem.

Comment: I don't think it's fixed.  I am running Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132), and today my WiFi process is taking 26.34 GB.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a normal situation as well - see my answers here:

- [Why is my Wi-Fi process using 3GB of memory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362861/why-is-my-wi-fi-process-using-3gb-of-memory)
- [Why is my Wi-Fi Process eating >2GB memory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349250/why-is-my-wi-fi-process-eating-2gb-memory)

I don't think there is any leak or issue on Apple side - just some programs you run open lots of connections and if they have bugs or you have more tabs open one day versos another and the specific web pages with trackers in the hundreds can really pile on - so the explanation could be more about what specific requests are made each session you use your Mac.

Comment: Why would a bug in another program lead the system process WiFi to consume so much memory?  As mentioned elsewhere, I reached 26GB today, and I don't do any unusual networking.  This seems like a flaw with the system process to allow this to happen, regardless of what other programs are trying to do.

Comment: @JessRiedel what if the program opens connection after connection after connection and never released them. The system provides services and poor programming can overload it.

Comment: A well-constructed service would alert the user  ("process X has requested too many connections") and possibly reject further requests. The key idea is that you should not allow a broken process to consume system resources *under WiFi's name* without giving the user a path toward isolating the problem.