# why is wifi using a lot of RAM?

Tags: macos, wifi, mojave

I recently updated to macOS Mojave, after update sometimes my wifi is using more than GB of RAM (seen in a process named "Wi-Fi" in "Activity Monitor.app").

Now I want to know why it is consuming so much RAM ? 
and how can i stop it from eating up free memory ?

Here are some details form the respective detail page from "Activity Monitor.app":

```
cwd
/
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/WiFiAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/WiFiAgent
txt
/Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.dIA1EUHh
txt
/usr/share/icu/icudt62l.dat
txt
/System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/AppleKeyboardLayouts-L.dat
txt
/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.kbdx
txt
/private/var/folders/jw/p_n01_pj0pz83nqp62m9l5cc0000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices-231-v2.csstore
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/SystemAppearance.car
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/DarkAquaAppearance.car
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/DarkAppearance.car
txt
/usr/lib/dyld
0
/dev/null
1
/dev/null
2
/dev/null
3
/dev/io8log
4
/dev/io8logtemp
5
*:*
```

right now it is using only 70 MB

Comment: which WiFi specific, WiFiVelocityd, WiFiVelocityAgent, WiFiProxy, or other ?

Comment: just Wi-Fi not anything before and after.

Comment: it should not be using any RAM, can you post a screen shot of that

Comment: Alternatively double click on that WiFi (in Activity Monitor) than click on Open Files & Ports, then copy the information and post here in you post.

Comment: added in original question too long to be pasted as comment

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Mojave VM operates on memory pressure model. If you have no memory pressure - even a GB or tens of GB of ram allocation are meaningless in a performance or resource manner. This will need a substantial edit to be clear or useful. Great start to editing in some snippet of some tool - remember - comments will be deleted, the question needs to be edited to stand alone and explain all the research being shown.

Comment: OK, since now is down to 70MB, you need to take the screen show when is up to 1 GB again.  For that turn off WiFi then wait 5 minutes and Turn it on again.

Comment: I have the same issue: Activity Monitor showing a process named "Wi-Fi" eating up almost 2 gigs of ram. The log above comes from the processes detail page in Activity Monitor.

Comment: See [question 340286](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340286/wi-fi-taking-up-lot-of-memory) for the mostly highly voted version of this question.  See [comment490174_362862](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362861/why-is-my-wi-fi-process-using-3gb-of-memory#comment490174_362862) for my rebuttal to bmike's suggestion that high memory usage by Wi-Fi is not important/meaningful because of it's only virtual memory.