# Wi-Fi process using up to 16GB of memory

Tags: mac, wifi, memory, mojave

Sometimes when I switch Wi-Fi network or connect to a VPN via Global Protect the memory usage of `/System/Library/CoreServices/WiFiAgent.app` shoots up and my fans go mental. Why?

[image]

This screenshot is one of the worst times it has happened, the usage is not alway consistent sometimes its 2GB, sometimes 6GB etc etc

Basic macbook pro 13" 2017

Comment: Hi Will, I've identified the Wi-Fi application on my computer and it's not using a large amount of memory. I presume you're using the latest version of Mojave?

Comment: @EzekielElin I believe that I am, if not I shouldn't be too far out of date. For the most part the application works fine like yours is but sometimes it spikes and it spikes high!

Comment: Thanks, there was enough information to identify the application involved  (which is part of macOS actually). No clue what's going on though.

Comment: Taken from @chrisdahfuh's answer: "Also, are you streaming/uploading/downloading anything? I see Google Chrome is using 1GB? Does it only happen when Google Chrome is open?"

Comment: Most highly upvoted version of this question: [340286](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340286/wi-fi-taking-up-lot-of-memory).

Answer (score 1):

This link provides instructions on how to reset your wifi configuration and removing/resetting specific plist files on your system under "Make a New Wi-Fi Configuration in MacOS Mojave" (with other useful Wifi tips), it could possibly help:

http://osxdaily.com/2018/11/19/fix-macos-mojave-wifi-problems/

Answer (score 0):

This is expected if you have a lot of networking. I'll close this as a duplicate of a couple questions covering this, but if you @ me in comments if you edit this to cover new ground we can revisit the hold / close.